# How to detect performance issues in function working on temporary tables?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a function which creates many **temporary** tables and performs inserts, updates, deletes and selects on them.
Some columns are textual and I have a lot of `SIMILAR TO` operations going on

The function is taking too long to execute and I don't know how to detect the problem, because I can't do an `explain analyze` on **temporary** tables to detect expensive operations.

What could possibly be done? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) extension to explain slow queries automatically from their native environment.  It will have no trouble seeing the temp tables.

You could manually load the extension if you are a superuser.  But this module is useful enough I just always put it (as well as pg_stat_statements) into shared_preload_libraries in postgresql.conf, that way it is always available.  The syntax for activating it in a specific client connection would be then be `set auto_explain.log_min_duration = '150ms';` and `set auto_explain.log_analyze=on;`.  The output goes to the database server's log file.  You can also have it sent to the client, by doing `set client_min_messages TO log;`, but I don't know what C# will do with such messages once it receives them through that channel.

Comment: okay, if the output goes to a log file, then I can check the log after execution. I will give that a try and give you feedback.

Comment: I added the following to config file: session_preload_libraries = 'auto_explain' - 
auto_explain.log_min_duration = '80ms' - 
auto_explain.log_analyze = on - 
auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on .. I restarted the server, and ran a query which took more than 100ms. A log file was created, but its content had nothing to do with my query. It had a plan for a query over tables : pg_stat_activity and pg_stat_database  !

Comment: How did you measure?  Could it be that >20ms was spent in sending data to the client or something like that?  You could set log_min_duration to 0, but just on one connection to avoid spurious logging.

Comment: When I execute the query in PgAdmin, it displays "Total query runtime" in msec. So after modifying config file and restarting server, I ran a query just to check if its plan gets 
 logged. But it wasn't !

Comment: when I ran my C# client, logging worked !

Answer (score 0):

> Quote: *I can't do an explain analyze on temporary tables to detect expensive
> operations.*

It's not common to execute EXPLAIN ANALYZE inside a function but it's doable in plpgsql, with either:

- `explain (analyze,format json) INTO varname <insert-your-query-here>;`

  `varname` will contain the entire plan in json format. Then it can be sent immediately to the client with

  ```
  raise notice '%', varname;
  ```

  or put into a session variable with:

  ```
  execute format('SET debug.myplan TO %L', varname);
  ```

  for later inspection in the session with `show debug.myplan;` or `select current_setting('debug.myplan');`
- Or iterate over the output lines of the classic multi-line output format, reassembling them into a text variable:

  ```
  declare
    line text, myplan text:='';
  begin
   for line in explain analyze  <insert-your-query-here>
   loop
     myplan:=myplan||line||chr(10);
   end loop;
   raise notice '%', myplan;
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I used the "auto_explain" extension. But anyway I have a question about your way. First: In case I want all statements of function to be logged, will I have to execute explain (analyze,format json) before each statement? Second:  normally when explain analyze is executed, the output is the plan, and not the actual result of the query. Is the behavior different when explain (analyze,format json)  is used within a function ?

Comment: @Nina: #1: yes. #2: no. Also `explain` can be used without analyze to separate running the query from reading its plan.